# Media server's VPN interfering with SOME local network (but not all). How to troubleshoot?

Tags: networking, vpn

All devices on same subnet.

Ubuntu 12.04LTS desktop (but functioning as headless server) auto connects to a VPN (purpose to anonymize internet activity for server only - nothing to do with other devices on network).  Wired connection to router.

Various mixed devices on Network incl:  WIN8 desktop (wired), Win7 laptop (wireless), Android (wireless), etc.

Problem:  When the VPN is active, SOME network activity is hindered.  Specifically, DLNA does't work and Plex Media Server doesn't work at clients.  However, server's Samba shares are discoverable and SSH works perfectly fine.

Turning off the VPN immediately resolves the problem.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot from here.

Comment: Ok, odd but I found a solution.  Order matters!  Having the VPN come on AFTER the affected services then solves the problem.  While I don't know why, it is consistant.  For example, the Plex Media Server.  If I turn the VPN on then start the server, the clients can't find it.  If, however, I turn the server off, turn the VPN off, turn the server back on and THEN turn the VPN on... all is fine.  Same for DLNA.  So now I have to look at my startup scripts carefully and make sure the order is respected and VPN is turned on last.

Comment: If you start the VPN first, the server probably binds to it instead of the LAN - maybe look into "Split Tunneling".  Anyhow, if you found an answer, please post it as an answer (you're allowed to answer your own questions).